# Reading a posted XML file in a c# webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, post, xml-parsing

I am very new to webservices in c#.

I posted an XML into a web service with the following function:

```
public static XmlDocument PostXMLTransaction(string URL, XmlDocument XMLDoc)
        {
            //Declare XMLResponse document
        XmlDocument XMLResponse = null;

        //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
        HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest;

    //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class
    HttpWebResponse objHttpWebResponse = null;

    //Declare a generic view of a sequence of bytes
    Stream objRequestStream = null;
    Stream objResponseStream = null;

    //Declare XMLReader
    XmlTextReader objXMLReader;

    //Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL.
    objHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

    try
    {
        //---------- Start HttpRequest

        //Set HttpWebRequest properties
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XMLDoc.InnerXml);
        objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        objHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

        //Get Stream object
        objRequestStream = objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

        //Writes a sequence of bytes to the current stream
        objRequestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        //Close stream
        objRequestStream.Close();

        //---------- End HttpRequest

        //Sends the HttpWebRequest, and waits for a response.
        objHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        //---------- Start HttpResponse
        if (objHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //Get response stream
            objResponseStream = objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

            //Load response stream into XMLReader
            objXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(objResponseStream);

            //Declare XMLDocument
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(objXMLReader);

            //Set XMLResponse object returned from XMLReader
            XMLResponse = xmldoc;

            //Close XMLReader
            objXMLReader.Close();
        }

        //Close HttpWebResponse
        objHttpWebResponse.Close();
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        //TODO: Add custom exception handling
        throw new Exception(we.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        //Close connections
        objRequestStream.Close();
        objResponseStream.Close();
        objHttpWebResponse.Close();

        //Release objects
        objXMLReader = null;
        objRequestStream = null;
        objResponseStream = null;
        objHttpWebResponse = null;
        objHttpWebRequest = null;
    }
    //Return
    return XMLResponse;
}
```

Now how do I read this XML into an XmlDocument in the webservice specified by the url parameter. I am not sure if it is possible to post data to webservices, correct me if I am wrong

I have used this method to post xml to aspx pages but not services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution

```
[WebMethod]
public string sendXliff()
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    //if (Request.InputStream != null)
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream!=null)
    {

        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
        string xmls = stream.ReadToEnd();  // added to view content of input stream
        //XDocument xmlInput = XDocument.Parse(xmls);
        xmldoc.LoadXml(xmls);
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.Schemas.Add(null, "XSD LOCATION");
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmldoc.InnerXml), settings);
        while (rdr.Read()) { }
    }
    try
    {
        XmlNodeList xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("ID");
        var sid = xmlnode[0].FirstChild.Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return "OK";
}
```

This reads the input stream and then convert the read data into XmlDocument. And then from this I can parse the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example of reading a XML Document. If it is a single node then use [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx)

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = PostXMLTransaction(string URL, XmlDocument XMLDoc) // call to your code for xml document
XmlNode node= xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("you xml node path here");
if(node != null)
{
   var str = node.InnerText;
}
```

If it is nodelist then use [XmlNodeList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodeList.aspx)

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("you xml node path here");
if(nodes != null)
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
         --code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I needed this but I want to know how I can read this posted xml document in the webservice.

Comment: what do you meant? do you want to read it once after the response?

Comment: not after the response, as you can see I am posting an XML file into a web service, i need to read this XML in the service.

Comment: Thanks @DON for your replies, i got the solution, i have added it as answer. I had this custom web service to which I was posting data to. So I wanted to read the XML that was posted in this webservice.

Comment: can u tell me how to specify the XML node path? It will be very helpfull